# Issue with aggregation query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here we have following query:

```
db.getCollection('triggered_policies').aggregate(
[{ "$match" : { "policy_name" : "EIQSVCFG-2111-Spam Activity"}}, 
{ "$project" : { "cust_created_at" : { "$add" : [ "$created_at" , 19800000]} , "event_ids" : "$event_ids" , "trigger_time" : "$trigger_time" , "created_at" : "$created_at" , "triggered_rules" : "$triggered_rules"}},
{ "$sort" : { "created_at" : -1}},
{ "$group" : 
    { "_id" : 
        { 
            "$hour" : "$cust_created_at"} , 
            "triggered_policies" : { "$addToSet" : { "trigger_time" : "$trigger_time" , "created_at" : "$created_at" , "event_ids" : "$event_ids" , "triggered_rules" : "$triggered_rules"}
        }
    }
}, 
{ "$sort" : { "_id" : 1}}
])
```

The ouput of above query is :

```
{
    "_id" : 11,
    "triggered_policies" : [ 
        {
            "trigger_time" : NumberLong(1484633489000),
            "created_at" : ISODate("2017-01-17T06:11:05.452Z"),
            "event_ids" : [ 
                "000159ab0c6c3c722f6249", 
                "000159ab0c6c3b722f624a"
            ],
            "triggered_rules" : [ 
                {
                    "policy_rule" : ObjectId("58776ea2a7c5541661c0424c"),
                    "trigger_time" : NumberLong(1484633489000),
                    "event_ids" : [ 
                        "000159ab0c6c3c722f6249", 
                        "000159ab0c6c3b722f624a"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "trigger_time" : NumberLong(1484633489000),
            "created_at" : ISODate("2017-01-17T06:11:05.453Z"),
            "event_ids" : [ 
                "000159ab0c6c3c722f6249", 
                "000159ab0c6c3b722f624a"
            ],
            "triggered_rules" : [ 
                {
                    "policy_rule" : ObjectId("58776ea2a7c5541661c0424c"),
                    "trigger_time" : NumberLong(1484633489000),
                    "event_ids" : [ 
                        "000159ab0c6c3c722f6249", 
                        "000159ab0c6c3b722f624a"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "trigger_time" : NumberLong(1484633489000),
            "created_at" : ISODate("2017-01-17T06:11:05.454Z"),
            "event_ids" : [ 
                "000159ab0c6c3c722f6248", 
                "000159ab0c6c3b722f624b"
            ],
            "triggered_rules" : [ 
                {
                    "policy_rule" : ObjectId("58776ea2a7c5541661c0424c"),
                    "trigger_time" : NumberLong(1484633489000),
                    "event_ids" : [ 
                        "000159ab0c6c3c722f6248", 
                        "000159ab0c6c3b722f624b"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**But what we are expecting is:**

In above query we are removing duplicate values of the combination of following fields:

```
 - trigger_time
 - created_at
 - event_ids
 - triggered_rules
```

But we need to have unique values of following three fields:

```
 - trigger_time
 - event_ids
 - triggered_rules
```

And first field value of `created_at` field.

I.e., the expected out put is attached in following image: [image]

Please help us to get the query (will provide input data also if you want).

My input is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("587db579a7c554598e3bb56e"),
    "policy_name" : "EIQSVCFG-2111-Spam Activity",
    "event_ids" : [ 
        "000159ab0c6c3c722f6249", 
        "000159ab0c6c3b722f624a"
    ],
    "trigger_time" : NumberLong(1484633489000),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-01-17T06:11:05.452Z"),
    "triggered_rules" : [ 
        {
            "policy_rule" : ObjectId("58776ea2a7c5541661c0424c"),
            "trigger_time" : NumberLong(1484633489000),
            "event_ids" : [ 
                "000159ab0c6c3c722f6249", 
                "000159ab0c6c3b722f624a"
            ]
        }
    ]
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("587f0801a34837e4ff3c5deb"),
    "policy_name" : "EIQSVCFG-2111-Spam Activity",
    "event_ids" : [ 
        "000159ab0c6c3c722f6249", 
        "000159ab0c6c3b722f624a"
    ],
    "trigger_time" : NumberLong(1484633489000),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-01-17T06:11:05.452Z"),
    "triggered_rules" : [ 
        {
            "policy_rule" : ObjectId("58776ea2a7c5541661c0424c"),
            "trigger_time" : NumberLong(1484633489000),
            "event_ids" : [ 
                "000159ab0c6c3c722f6249", 
                "000159ab0c6c3b722f624a"
            ]
        }
    ]
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("587f0807a34837e4ff3c5dec"),
    "policy_name" : "EIQSVCFG-2111-Spam Activity",
    "event_ids" : [ 
        "000159ab0c6c3c722f6249", 
        "000159ab0c6c3b722f624a"
    ],
    "trigger_time" : NumberLong(1484633489000),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-01-17T06:11:05.452Z"),
    "triggered_rules" : [ 
        {
            "policy_rule" : ObjectId("58776ea2a7c5541661c0424c"),
            "trigger_time" : NumberLong(1484633489000),
            "event_ids" : [ 
                "000159ab0c6c3c722f6249", 
                "000159ab0c6c3b722f624a"
            ]
        }
    ]
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("587f0811a34837e4ff3c5ded"),
    "policy_name" : "EIQSVCFG-2111-Spam Activity",
    "event_ids" : [ 
        "000159ab0c6c3c722f6249", 
        "000159ab0c6c3b722f624a"
    ],
    "trigger_time" : NumberLong(1484633489000),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-01-17T06:11:05.452Z"),
    "triggered_rules" : [ 
        {
            "policy_rule" : ObjectId("58776ea2a7c5541661c0424c"),
            "trigger_time" : NumberLong(1484633489000),
            "event_ids" : [ 
                "000159ab0c6c3c722f6249", 
                "000159ab0c6c3b722f624a"
            ]
        }
    ]
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("587f0861a34837e4ff3c5dee"),
    "policy_name" : "EIQSVCFG-2111-Spam Activity",
    "event_ids" : [ 
        "000159ab0c6c3c722f6249", 
        "000159ab0c6c3b722f624a"
    ],
    "trigger_time" : NumberLong(1484633489000),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-01-17T06:11:05.453Z"),
    "triggered_rules" : [ 
        {
            "policy_rule" : ObjectId("58776ea2a7c5541661c0424c"),
            "trigger_time" : NumberLong(1484633489000),
            "event_ids" : [ 
                "000159ab0c6c3c722f6249", 
                "000159ab0c6c3b722f624a"
            ]
        }
    ]
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("587f2932a34837e4ff3c5def"),
    "policy_name" : "EIQSVCFG-2111-Spam Activity",
    "event_ids" : [ 
        "000159ab0c6c3c722f6248", 
        "000159ab0c6c3b722f624b"
    ],
    "trigger_time" : NumberLong(1484633489000),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-01-17T06:11:05.454Z"),
    "triggered_rules" : [ 
        {
            "policy_rule" : ObjectId("58776ea2a7c5541661c0424c"),
            "trigger_time" : NumberLong(1484633489000),
            "event_ids" : [ 
                "000159ab0c6c3c722f6248", 
                "000159ab0c6c3b722f624b"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And the expected out would be:

```
{
    "_id" : 11,
    "triggered_policies" : [ 
        {
            "trigger_time" : NumberLong(1484633489000),
            "created_at" : ISODate("2017-01-17T06:11:05.452Z"),
            "event_ids" : [ 
                "000159ab0c6c3c722f6249", 
                "000159ab0c6c3b722f624a"
            ],
            "triggered_rules" : [ 
                {
                    "policy_rule" : ObjectId("58776ea2a7c5541661c0424c"),
                    "trigger_time" : NumberLong(1484633489000),
                    "event_ids" : [ 
                        "000159ab0c6c3c722f6249", 
                        "000159ab0c6c3b722f624a"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "trigger_time" : NumberLong(1484633489000),
            "created_at" : ISODate("2017-01-17T06:11:05.454Z"),
            "event_ids" : [ 
                "000159ab0c6c3c722f6248", 
                "000159ab0c6c3b722f624b"
            ],
            "triggered_rules" : [ 
                {
                    "policy_rule" : ObjectId("58776ea2a7c5541661c0424c"),
                    "trigger_time" : NumberLong(1484633489000),
                    "event_ids" : [ 
                        "000159ab0c6c3c722f6248", 
                        "000159ab0c6c3b722f624b"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Avoid posting images for code, this is not encouraged on StackOverflow

Comment: I've edited my answer, and the query as well. You can try that aggregation query once again, but note that your provided output has the same `trigger_time` field.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

Your provided output does not satisfy your requirement, because the trigger_time field in both docs are the same, whereas you require them to be unique.
So the following aggregation satisfies your provided requirement.

```
db.getCollection('triggered_policies').aggregate([
  { $match : { "policy_name" : "EIQSVCFG-2111-Spam Activity"}},
  { $project : { created_at : { $add : [ "$created_at" , 19800000]}, triggered_rules:1, trigger_time:1, event_ids:1}},

  { $sort : { "created_at" : -1}}, 
  { $unwind:"$triggered_rules"}, //this will unwind the array of triggered_rules
  { $group:{_id:"$triggered_rules", created_at: {$first: "$created_at"}, event_ids: {$first: "$event_ids"}, trigger_time: {$first: "$trigger_time"}}}, //this will give unique triggered_rules
  { $project : { created_at : 1, triggered_rules:"$_id", trigger_time:1, event_ids:1}},

  { $group:{_id:"$event_ids", created_at: {$first: "$created_at"}, trigger_time: {$first: "$trigger_time"}, triggered_rules: {$first: "$triggered_rules"}}}, //will give unique event_ids field
  { $project : { created_at : 1, triggered_rules:1, trigger_time:1, event_ids:"$_id"}},

  //and finally making unique created_at and trigger_time fileds
  { $group:{_id:"$created_at", trigger_time: {$first: "$trigger_time"}, event_ids: {$first: "$event_ids"}, triggered_rules:    {$first: "$triggered_rules"}}}, //this will give you unique created_at fields
  { $project : { created_at : "$_id", triggered_rules:1, trigger_time:1, event_ids:1}},
  { $group:{_id:"$trigger_time", created_at: {$first: "$created_at"}, event_ids: {$first: "$event_ids"}, triggered_rules: {$first: "$triggered_rules"}}}, //and this will give you unique trigger_time fields    
  { $project : { created_at : 1, triggered_rules:1, trigger_time:"$_id", event_ids:1}},

])
```

Based on your provided input this gives me the following output:

```
{
"_id" : NumberLong("1484633489000"),
"created_at" : ISODate("2017-01-17T11:41:05.453Z"),
"event_ids" : [
    "000159ab0c6c3c722f6249",
    "000159ab0c6c3b722f624a"
],
"triggered_rules" : {
    "policy_rule" : ObjectId("58776ea2a7c5541661c0424c"),
    "trigger_time" : NumberLong("1484633489000"),
    "event_ids" : [
        "000159ab0c6c3c722f6249",
        "000159ab0c6c3b722f624a"
    ]
},
"trigger_time" : NumberLong("1484633489000")
}
```

Comment: Thank You Karlen for your quick reply,

And sorry to say that this is giving wrong output.

regards,      
Jagadeesh Musham

Comment: Can provide the input documents, that will help to give better answer? More than 5 docs will be appreciated

Comment: Updated the input and expected output in first comment.

Comment: I've edited my answer, and the query as well. You can try that aggregation query once again, but note that your provided output has the same `trigger_time` field

Comment: Thank You Karlen, though the trigger time is same in my expected output but event-ids are different.